# Fragmentation of packets in 802.11p MAC layer in VEINS

Tags: omnet++, veins

I am implementing an application aware of the MAC layer in Veins simulator.

My question is where I can get the behavior of the 802.11p fragmentation in Veins MAC layer? (It is about 1500 bytes in the Ethernet architecture).

My question lies in the fact that I want transmit a video but I don't want fragmentation in MAC layer. But reviewing the MAC layer code, I did not find how the fragmentation is performed.

Thank you in beforehand by the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MAC layer of Veins up to and including the current Veins 4.7.1 is given ready-to-send frames (not datagrams, segments, or packets). If fragmentation is to be performed, it has to be done by the module feeding frames to the MAC layer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer Prof. Sommer. I only ask to confirm. Best Regards.